# Best way to do exponential regression with ranged x values

Tags: exponential-function

Given the following data

[image]

What is the best way to exponential regression to function $f(x) = Ce^{kx}$. I thought of replacing the ranges with the value in the middle so that for example $0 \leq x <1$ becomes $0.5$. But what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/dae/interval-regression/